# Insert record in mysql with adonisjs jsonb field

Tags: javascript, typescript, adonis.js, lucid

I'm trying to insert a record where one of the fields is of type JSONB

Below is the format I'm trying to build and at the end the error that is being issued.

The field in question is veiculo

orm is trying to access the inside of the json to try to indetify the field.

It should insert the complete object.

I thank the attention. Thanks.

Post

```
{
  veiculo: {
    placa: 'PLACA',
    motorista: 'NOME',
    contato: 'CONTATO',
    casa: true,
    horaEntrada: '2022-01-20T05:02:22.000Z'
  },
  fornecedor: 'ALIMENTOS',
  lab: 'sim',
}
```

Model

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon'
import { BaseModel, column } from '@ioc:Adonis/Lucid/Orm'

export default class Produto extends BaseModel {
  @column({ isPrimary: true })
  public id: number

  @column()
  public fornecedor: string

  @column()
  public lab: string

  @column()
  public veiculo: Object

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true })
  public createdAt: DateTime

  @column.dateTime({ autoCreate: true, autoUpdate: true })
  public updatedAt: DateTime
```

Migration

```
public async up () {
    this.schema.createTable(this.tableName, (table) => {
      table.increments('id')
      table.string('fornecedor'
      table.string('lab')
      table.jsonb('veiculo')

      /**
       * Uses timestamptz for PostgreSQL and DATETIME2 for MSSQL
       */
      table.timestamp('created_at', { useTz: true })
      table.timestamp('updated_at', { useTz: true })
    })
  }
```

Error

> Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'placa' in 'field list'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved with await dataNfe.related('items').createMany(items)